# How to define system()

Tags: c, bash, operating-system

So I want to define system() function! Here is my function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void mySystem (char *command)
{    
    execlp (command, command, (char*) 0);
}

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{    
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) 
    {
        char command[50];
        strcpy(command, argv[i]);
        mySystem(command);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And then I try it and it is like that:

```
gcc exe6.c;
./a.out ls ls
```

In this case it only does one ls.

```
./a.out "ls -l"
```

In this case doesn't do anything. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) actually tells you how to do it:

> The system() library function uses fork(2) to create a child process that executes the shell command specified in command using execl(3) as follows:
>
> ```
> execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", command, (char *) 0);
> ```
>
> system() returns after the command has been completed.